# No hago funcionar mis relaciones con elocuent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

tengo una base de datos que tiene las siguiente tabla.
[image: Tabla usuarios]

En esta tabla usuarios tengo tres campos que son llaves foráneas, solo reciben el id de otra tabla. Lo que yo quiero hacer es que al momento de listar los usuarios mostrar en pantalla la ciudad, estado o puesto al que esta relacionado este id, no el numero entero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla estados que se relaciona con la de usuarios de aquí solo utilizo la relación del id para acceder al nombre el problema es que al acceder al método $user->estado->nombre me arroja este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en cambio si haciendo pruebas y moviendole un poco me percate que al solo poner el metodo de este modo $user->estado (sin intentar traer la propiedad nombre) me trae este objeto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me seria de mucha ayuda que alguien me pudiese decir si estoy haciendo un correcto uso de las relaciones, o cual esta siendo mi error.
Estas son la relaciones que declare en mis modelos User y Estado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando traes el objeto sin acceder al nombre, te saca un objeto en blanco entre las 4 llamadas? Puedes enseñarnos el codigo donde ocurre el error?

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido cuando traigo el objeto de este modo $user->estado me trae el objeto de la imagen de arriba,  cuando accedo al nombre $user->estado->nombre es cuando me marca el error

Comment: Hagamos las siguientes pruebas: en en modelo estado, cambia el nombre de la función `user()` a `users()`. Intenta acceder a la propiedad de la siguiente manera: `$user->estado['nombre']`. Y si no, en la declaracion de la relación en el modelo user pon esto: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Estado')->withDefault()`. (No te hace falta declarar el nombre de la foreign key, ya que Laravel asume que sera "modelo + _id"). Dicho esto y mirando tu codigo... creo que el fallo es una errata en `BelongsTo`, que deberia ser `belongsTo`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @FranciscoGarrido, tendre mas cuidado con esas detalles la proxima, todo quedo funcionando tal y como queria!! GRACIAS

Comment: Si puedes, responde a tu propia pregunta con la respuesta de cual era el problema, puede servir de ayuda para otras personas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hagamos las siguientes pruebas: en en modelo estado, cambia el nombre de la función user() a users(). Intenta acceder a la propiedad de la siguiente manera: $user->estado['nombre']. Y si no, en la declaracion de la relación en el modelo user pon esto: return $this->belongsTo('App\Estado')->withDefault(). (No te hace falta declarar el nombre de la foreign key, ya que Laravel asume que sera "modelo + _id"). Dicho esto y mirando tu codigo... creo que el fallo es una errata en BelongsTo, que deberia ser belongsTo

Comment: Estas respondiendo a tu propia pregunta cierto?

Comment: asi es, me comento un usuario de arriba que lo hiciera, el me dio la respuesta, o hay otro modo de hacerlo?